# FB Comment 'Also Post on Facebook' and FB Share - Linkback to different URLs?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

This is *SO* annoying.

The Issue is a matter of two scenarios behaving differently when I expect (and wish) them to be the same, these relate to the same webpage/article which features both Facebook Comment widget and a Share icon.

It's important to mention that the webpage is a Wordpress article, and we redirect:

- **from** www.example.com/wordpress/articles/news/thearticle
- **to** www.example.com/news/thearticle

The issue explained:

**Scenario 1)** I visit the article and type a facebook comment, I also click 'Also Post on Facebook'. When I view may facebook wall and see the share with the comment I just made, the link is linking back to the wordpress URL - I do not want this.

**Scenario 2)** I visit the article and share it through the Share icon. On my wall this time the linkback URL is the short one - this is good.

**Important info regarding debugging**

My OG URL tag is correct:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/news/thearticle"/>
```

- Facebook debugger is picking up the correct desired URL as above,
  also listing the desired Fetched URL and Canonical URL. All seems to
  be what I want it to be.
- This is true regardless of whether or not I
  scrape the URL before or after I try this procedure.
- Even if I then go back and do another comment with 'also post on FB' after doing a scrape with FB debugger, still the share links to the wrong/long format/original URL.
- **However, if I at any point share via the share icon, not the comment-share, the desired URL is present as per the OG URL.**
- If I do a comment-share, then an icon-share, then another comment-share, the comment share ones still have the wrong URL even though the icon-share had the correct one!

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance to anyone who can help :)

Comment: How do you post your comments to facebook? Are you using any plugin? If so, which one?

Comment: No sir, just the native HTML supplied by facebook: DIV Class="FB Comments", numposts="6" data-version="v2.3"

Comment: You should be able to force the url using the `data-href` attribute, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#settings

Comment: @vard After all this time investigating OG:URL, it seems you are correct, my issue is with the dyamic URL pushed into the comment HREF tag being the old/long/undesired URL. As soon as I've checked this code in and assuming it works, I will happily mark you as the approved answer if you care to create an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Comments FB plugin doesn't get the page info from OpenGraph, but expect a `data-href` attribute, or if not provided will use the current url by default.

[From the doc:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#settings)

> **data-href**
>
> *Description :* The absolute URL that comments posted in the plugin will be permanently associated with. Stories on Facebook about comments posted in the plugin will link to this URL.
>
> *Default :* Current URL.

So what you need to do is to provide the valid URL as an HTML5 attribute on your plugin wrapper:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/news/thearticle" data-numposts="5"></div>
```